# How to efficiently remove (or add) leading zeros on IP addresses in R?

Tags: r, ip

Two dataframes in R each contain fields for IP addresses. In each dataframe, these fields are "factors". The user intends to merge the two dataframes based on these IP addresses as well as a few other fields. The problem is that each dataframe has different formats for the IPs:

```
Dataframe A examples: 123.456.789.123, 123.012.001.123, 987.001.010.100
```

The same IPs in Dataframe B would be formatted as:

```
Dataframe B examples: 123.456.789.123, 123.12.1.123, 987.1.10.100
```

What is the best (most efficient) way to either remove the leading zeros from A or add them to B so they can be used in a merge? The operation will be performed over millions of records so 'most efficient' is in consideration of compute time (needs to be relatively quick).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to format the sections.  For instance, you could do the following, for a given numeric value `a`:

```
b <- sprintf("%.3d", a)
```

So, for an IP address, try this function:

```
printPadded <- function(x){
  retStr = paste(sprintf("%.3d",unlist(lapply(strsplit(x,"\\.", perl = TRUE), as.numeric))), collapse = ".")
  return(retStr)
}
```

Here are two examples:

```
> printPadded("1.2.3.4")
[1] "001.002.003.004"

> lapply(c("1.2.3.4","5.67.100.9"), printPadded)
[[1]]
[1] "001.002.003.004"

[[2]]
[1] "005.067.100.009"
```

To go in the other direction, we can remove leading zeros, using `gsub` on the splitted values in the `printPadded` function.  For my money, I'd recommend not removing the leading zeros.  It's not necessary to remove zeros (or to pad them), but fixed width formats are easier to read and to sort (i.e. for those sorting functions that are lexicographic).

---

Update 1: Just a speed suggestion: if you are dealing with a lot of IP addresses, and really want to speed this up, you might look at multicore methods, such as `mclapply`.  The `plyr` package is also useful, with `ddply()` as one option.  These also support parallel backends, via `.parallel = TRUE`.  Still, a few million IP addresses shouldn't take very long even on a single core.

Comment: Whoa, thanks for the quick response. I'm getting an error 

**Error in strsplit(x, "\\.", perl = TRUE) : non-character argument**

Do I need to run as.character since they are currently factor levels?

Comment: I ran **lapply(as.character(data$IP), printPadded)** with success. Thanks. Waiting a few hours before accepting answer.

Comment: @Benjamin Ah, you should be careful about factors.  These can muck up everything, because sometimes they look like character vectors, but may end up being treated as integers.  If you load the data, say as `read.csv()`, look for the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  Alternatively, you can set this in your options - look at `?options`.  FWIW, I've never benefited from loading strings as factors - I only do explicit factor conversion when it's needed (e.g. in certain types of models)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is like this:

```
my @ipparts = split(/\./, $ip);
for my $ii (0..$#ipparts)
{
    $ipparts[$ii] = $ipparts[$ii]+0;
}
$ip = join(".", @ipparts);
```

Nicer than a whole lot of divisions that sprintf requires.